# Three.js camera lookAt object freeze the rotation

Tags: three.js

Currently i have:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Collision Detection (Three.js)</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="js/libs/Three.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/Stats.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/THREEx.KeyboardState.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/THREEx.FullScreen.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/THREEx.WindowResize.js"></script>
    <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------ -->

    <div id="ThreeJS" ></div>
    <script>
        var main = new function()
        {
            this.SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
            this.SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
            this.VIEW_ANGLE = 45;
            this.ASPECT = this.SCREEN_WIDTH / this.SCREEN_HEIGHT;
            this.NEAR = 0.1;
            this.FAR = 20000;

            this.keyboard = new THREEx.KeyboardState();
            this.clock = new THREE.Clock();

            this.htmlContainer = null;

            this.scene = null;
            this.renderer = null;
            this.controls = null;

            //models
            this.player = null;

            this.main = function()
            {
                this.setScene();
                this.setCamera();
                this.setRenderer();
                this.setEvents();
                this.setControls();
                this.setStats();
                this.setLight();
                this.setFloor();
                this.setSky();
                this.setPlayer();
            };
            this.animate = function()
            {
                requestAnimationFrame( main.animate );
                main.renderer.render( main.scene, main.camera );
                main.runListener();

                //this.camera.position. = 0;
            };
            this.runListener = function()
            {
                var delta = this.clock.getDelta(); // seconds.
                var moveDistance = 200 * delta; // 200 pixels per second
                var rotateAngle = Math.PI / 2 * delta;   // pi/2 radians (90 degrees) per second

                // move forwards/backwards/left/right
                if ( this.keyboard.pressed("W") )
                    this.player.translateZ( -moveDistance );
                if ( this.keyboard.pressed("S") )
                    this.player.translateZ(  moveDistance );
                if ( this.keyboard.pressed("Q") )
                    this.player.translateX( -moveDistance );
                if ( this.keyboard.pressed("E") )
                    this.player.translateX(  moveDistance );

                // rotate left/right/up/down
                if ( this.keyboard.pressed("A") )
                    this.player.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), rotateAngle);
                if ( this.keyboard.pressed("D") )
                    this.player.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), -rotateAngle);


                var relativeCameraOffset = new THREE.Vector3(0,150,400);
                var cameraOffset = relativeCameraOffset.applyMatrix4( this.player.matrixWorld );

                this.camera.position.x = cameraOffset.x;
                this.camera.position.y = cameraOffset.y;
                this.camera.position.z = cameraOffset.z;
                this.camera.lookAt( this.player.position );

                this.camera.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), 0 );
                //this.camera.rotation.y = 0;
                //this.camera.children[0].rotation.x = 0;
                //yaw =

                //this.controls.update();
                this.stats.update();
            };
            this.setPlayer = function()
            {
                var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(50,50,50,1,1,1);
                var wireMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, wireframe:true } );
                this.player = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, wireMaterial );
                this.player.position.set(0, 25.1, 0);
                //this.player.add( this.camera );
                this.scene.add( this.player );
            };
            this.setRenderer = function()
            {
                if ( Detector.webgl )
                    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
                else
                    this.renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
                this.renderer.setSize( this.SCREEN_WIDTH, this.SCREEN_HEIGHT );
                this.htmlContainer = document.getElementById( 'ThreeJS' );
                this.htmlContainer.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );
            };
            this.setCamera = function()
            {
                this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( this.VIEW_ANGLE, this.ASPECT, this.NEAR, this.FAR );
                this.camera.noRotate = true;
                this.scene.add( this.camera );
            };
            this.setScene = function()
            {
                this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
            };
            this.setEvents = function()
            {
                THREEx.WindowResize( this.renderer, this.camera );
                THREEx.FullScreen.bindKey({ charCode: 'm'.charCodeAt(0) });
            };
            this.setControls = function()
            {
                this.controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( this.camera, this.renderer.domElement );
            };
            this.setLight = function()
            {
                var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
                light.position.set(0,250,0);
                this.scene.add(light);
            };
            this.setStats = function()
            {
                this.stats = new Stats();
                this.stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                this.stats.domElement.style.bottom = '0px';
                this.stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
                this.htmlContainer.appendChild( this.stats.domElement );
            };
            this.setFloor = function()
            {
                var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color:0x444444, side:THREE.DoubleSide} );
                var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000, 10, 10);
                floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
                floor.position.y = -0.5;
                floor.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
                this.scene.add( floor );
            };
            this.setSky = function()
            {
                var skyBoxGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10000, 10000, 10000 );
                var skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x9999ff, side: THREE.BackSide } );
                var skyBox = new THREE.Mesh( skyBoxGeometry, skyBoxMaterial );
                //this.scene.add(skyBox);
            };
        };


        main.main();
        main.animate();
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This example will feel like a FPS (use with keys WASD, QE). Im trying the figure out, how i can follow an object with the camera without rotating the camera, in the current sample you see:

```
     this.camera.lookAt( this.player.position );
     this.camera.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), 0 );
```

After looking at the "player", i want the camera to follow the object but without rotation. this is currently not working, any ideas?

**Edit: solved:

```
if ( this.keyboard.pressed("D") )
    this.player.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), -rotateAngle);


/*
var relativeCameraOffset = new THREE.Vector3(0,150,400);
var cameraOffset = relativeCameraOffset.applyMatrix4( this.player.matrixWorld );

this.camera.position.x = cameraOffset.x;
this.camera.position.y = cameraOffset.y;
this.camera.position.z = cameraOffset.z;
*/

this.camera.position.x = this.player.position.x;
this.camera.position.y = this.player.position.y+150;
this.camera.position.z = this.player.position.z+400;

this.camera.lookAt( this.player.position );

//this.controls.update();
this.stats.update();
```

Comment: I might be wrong but I think `rotateOnAxis` rotates by a relative value, so it does nothing in your case. You should try to reset the original `camera.rotation.y` value instead.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, that is what i tryed before but then the camera reacts as a swing.

Comment: I figured out how the camera lookAt works and i solved it by thinking logical, see the answer below the question